# Python3: Get rid of single quotes automatically added in a dictionary to pass it as a MongoDB query

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary

i try to build a dynamic MongoDB query. The object in the DB looks like this:

```
<id>
 <NMAP>
  <tcp>
   <22><..>
   <3389><..>
```

From a web interface users can define which port they want to filter. The Python code looks like this:

```
port = "NMAP.tcp"+search_port #Search Port is e.G. 3389
query[port] = "{$exists : true}"
items = mongo.db.nmaps.find(query)
```

The query looks like this: {'NMAP.tcp.3389': '{$exists : true}'}. I copy pasted this to the mongoshell and it gives no results. If I adjust the query (in the mongoshell) and get rid of the single quotes around the {$exists : true} part it works and i see multiple results.

Any idea how i can get this solved? I am also open for more elegant solutions ;-)

Thanks in advance and best regards,
 Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using a string in the first place. To pass queries to MongoDB using the Python driver, you use Python datastructures, eg dicts and booleans:

```
query[port] = {"$exists" : True}
items = mongo.db.nmaps.find(query)
```

Comment: What a simple solution ;-). Thank you very much!